# Change Command Prompt Title in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-prompt, titlebar

Is there anyway you can change the title of command prompt in Javascript like you can in python by importing ctypes and using `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("")`?

Comment: What do you mean "title of command prompt".  Do you mean in an OS console window?  What is the context?  Are you launching a child process from nodejs?

Comment: `process.title = 'yay!'`

Comment: There are also packages for that purpose like https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-title

Answer (score 0):

You may configure a custom message in the main prompt text area, but you may not customize the title bar of the prompt. However, when that is desired, most people just create a modal which is very easy to do.

```js
// You may customize the prompt message:
prompt("Enter a number:");

// Or you can create a custom modal:
document.querySelector(".showModal").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".modal").classList.remove("hidden");
});

document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.closest(".modal").classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { opacity:0; }
.modal { position:absolute; left:40%; height:40%; border:2px solid grey; background-color:#e0e0e0; }
.title { background-color:navy; color:white; font-weight:bold; }
.main {  color:black; padding:3px; }
```

```html
<div class="modal hidden">
  <div class="title">Custom Title</div>
  <div class="main">Main Content Here</div>
  <div>
    <button class="close">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="showModal">Press me to show the custom modal</button>
```